# Steam not starting MATE 15.10

Tags: 15.10, steam, mate

I installed steam on Ubuntu Mate 15.10, and i cannot open it.
I opened system monitor and I saw steam running, so i closed it and I reopened it and nothing.
Its status is sleeping if that helps.
I opened it in terminal and heres the output.

```
Running Steam on ubuntu 15.10 64-bit
STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(0)
libGL error: unable to load driver: nouveau_dri.so
libGL error: driver pointer missing
libGL error: failed to load driver: nouveau
libGL error: unable to load driver: swrast_dri.so
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try using the proprietary drivers instead (it works for me). You can do this in System>Preferences>Hardware>Additional Drivers. Also, if you are using Compiz as a Windows Manager,  I would suggest you avoid version 352.63 (it crashed OpenGL for me), but use the older version.

Comment: How would i check the compiz version? Edit: I am using version 0.9.12.2

Comment: The version I wrote (352.63) is a NVIDIA driver version which I found incompatible with Compiz. Just make sure you do not take that one, but the older stable release, They should all be listed in the Additional Driver window. It might be marked as "Legacy".